# Value return incorrectly after calculated field

Tags: sql, calculated-columns, calculated-field, sql-calc-found-rows

```
SELECT
    t3.id,
    t3.prod_ID,
    MIN(diff) AS min_time
FROM
    (SELECT
         t1.id,
         (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.time_stamp)) AS diff
     FROM 
         production t1
     LEFT JOIN 
         process t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
     HAVING 
         diff >= 0) tx
LEFT JOIN 
    production t3 ON t3.id = tx.id
GROUP BY
    t3.id
```

After run, the returned result is:

```
id  prod_ID   min_time
-----------------------
1   2         1200
```

What it should return instead is

```
id  prod_ID   min_time
1   9         1200
```

I initially thought there was an error in joining, after multiple join test, same error result.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/325587/1)

[SQLFiddle_2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1141c2/1)

[SQLFiddle_3](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ad86af/1)

**SQLFiddle_2** to clarify that I use Group By because I have multiple ID

**SQLFiddle_3** to expand more.

After run on SQLFiddle_3, the returned result is:

```
id  prod_ID   min_time
-----------------------
1   2         1200
2   2         960
3   2         360
```

What it should be is

```
id  prod_ID   min_time
-----------------------
1   9         1200
2   2         960
3   3         360
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query you `GROUP BY t3.id` only and you don't aggregate on `t3.prod_ID`, so the value returned is undefined.

I believe that you don't need to `GROUP BY`, or even rejoin to `production`.
Try this:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.prod_ID,
       (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.time_stamp)) AS diff
FROM production t1 INNER JOIN process t2
ON t1.id = t2.id 
AND (t1.id, t1.prod_ID) = (
  SELECT p.id, p.prod_ID
  FROM production p
  WHERE p.id = t2.id AND (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.time_stamp)) >= 0
  ORDER BY (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(p.time_stamp)) LIMIT 1
)
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=e13dc22bd17cc604c8032891d922604b).
Results:

```
> id | prod_ID | diff
> -: | ------: | ---:
>  1 |       9 | 1200
>  2 |       2 |  960
```

Comment: sorry @forpas, for clarification I edited my question. I cannot use LIMIT because/in case have multiple ID

Comment: @silver_river what is your version of MySql?

Comment: sorry, I am quite a beginner, MySQL 5.6

Comment: I also need to find the MIN after 'filtered' the negative value from calculated field.

Comment: sorry, one question. I didnt know that I can use 2 columns in this `AND (t1.id, t1.prod_ID)`, I thought can only use one like this `AND (t1.id)`. Can you share any material that I can read further. To be honest, I dont know what to Google that.

And one more, I only thought I can use, `AND (t1.id, t1.prod_ID)`, that 'AND' after 'WHERE' clause on filtering. Any material I can read further?

Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: @silver_river I think that you want this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/row-subqueries.html I do not understand what you mean in the 2nd part of your comment.

Comment: Thank you very much for the link, its very useful.
On second item.
Usually
`SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE condition1 AND condition2`
But in this case, you didnt have the WHERE clause.
If still not clear, can ignore it. You already help a lot.

Comment: Now I see what you mean. Both conditions are applied in the ON clause. Since this is an INNER join it would be the same to use WHERE instead of AND, so there are both ON and WHERE clauses. So in my code the filtering is done in the ON clause when the tables/queries are joined. If instead of AND I used a WHERE clause then the filtering would be done after the tables/queries were joined. The result is exactly the same (because it is an INNER JOIN).

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very wrong indeed, your inner query is essentially making a list of the time differences, but then you throw all this good work away and don't join or group on the prod_id, so it essentially just picks the first value you inserted into your database. If you switch the order you insert the data so prod_id is inserted first then you get the result you want, but for the wrong reason.

Your inner query is sort of doing this:

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.prod_id,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.time_stamp)) as diff
    FROM production t1
    left JOIN process t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
   WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.time_stamp)) > 0
```

If you run that you see the values you want:

```
id     prod_id    diff
1        2        1800
1        3        1380
1        9        1200
```

...but then your outer query does nothing with this.

There's many ways to do this, here's one simple method:

```
SELECT 
    t1.id,
    t1.prod_id,
    (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.time_stamp)) as diff
    FROM production t1
    left JOIN process t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
   WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t2.time_stamp_2)-UNIX_TIMESTAMP(t1.time_stamp)) > 0
   ORDER BY 3
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi Mr Hansell. I edited my question, I cannot use LIMIT because  (in case) have multiple ID

Comment: Good insight Mr Hansell, but I also need MIN after >0 'filter' from calculated field.